# Using Alternative DataSources in Sharepoint

Tags: database, sharepoint, wss-3.0

As I know, Sharepoint save all users list in one table. I have several sharepoint lists. And I want to store Data from Sharepoint lists in custom MS Sql Server DB. That difrent Sharepoint lists store data in diffrent tables. I want that this data is stored **only** in my custom DB (**not** in sharepoint DB).

And I also want that mutual (many-to-many) links between difrent lists in this DB are. For example I have 2 lists Projects and Emploeyrs one project can have many employers and one employer can work on several projects. I want that if I delete emploer from project link for that project is deleted from this emploer.

Could You recomend me some sollutions for this task?

Comment: So why use SharePoint at all? External Linked Lists are the way to go in SharePoint 2010 - in 2007 version, look at the BDC. Sounds like a lot of work for little, if any benefit.

Comment: As I know, BDC is a component of Sharepoint 2007. But I use only WSS-3.0.

Comment: You have the ability to link lists with relationships between them in all versions of SharePoint (lookup columns) You may need to look at workflows to handle cascading deletions though. But it could be achieved in WSS too. As I said though, lots of effort.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what your trying to do :\
You might want to look at this http://www.simego.com/Products/Data-Synchronisation-Studio and use dynamic columns

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a real mashup, I'd bee using some external components like the ASPxGridView from DevExpress, http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Grid/, to get the list views since you wont be able to use the internal lists.

To interface towards the internal SharePoint lists I'd use the Camelot .NET Connector from Bendsoft, http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/.

With that combination it wont really matter where you put the result, it can be used internally in SharePoint as well as externally and it dont matter if you use 2007 or newer either.